# Could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com when reinstalling xorg

Tags: 11.10, installation, xorg, recovery-mode, hybrid-graphics

I managed to uninstall xserver-xorg completely, and now all I see when booting Ubuntu is a blank screen. I've tried reinstalling it through shell prompt (recovery mode) but every time I get errors similar to

> Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg/xserver-xorg-input-all_7.6+7ubuntu7_amd64.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

I get similar (not exactly the same though) errors when running apt-get update or try to repair broken packages in recovery mode. It's not just acrhive.ubuntu.com which can't be resolved, it's also se.archive.ubuntu.com, repository.spotify.com, archive.canonical.com among others.

The Ubuntu desktop is not accessible, I can only make changes through the terminal in recovery mode, or through a bootable USB.

I'm running 64bit Ubuntu 11.10 with hybrid graphics (Intel HD and AMD).

I tried adding

> nameserver 8.8.8.8

to my /etc/resolv.conf file but it made no difference. Updating the hosts file [like this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=876616&page=2#12) didn't help either.

Running

> ping google.com

returns

> ping: unknown host google.com

It seems I'm not even connected to any network, I will start investigating this right now.

[apt.log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1128086/apt.log.txt) & [sources.list](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1128086/sources.list.txt)

What should I do?

Comment: did you try doing a `sudo apt-get update` before installing packages? or changing the download server mirrors?

Comment: I've added apt-get update to my question, same error there. By changing download server mirrors, do you mean like this? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=876616

Comment: You're having DNS issues. If `host example.com` hangs or fails, but `ping 192.0.43.10` works, you've confirmed it. Try setting the DNS server to `8.8.8.8` in Network Manager.

Comment: That might be the cause, only problem is I can't access Network Manager, or anything but the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by downloading some of the packages I needed through a bootable USB, and then installing them in shell prompt (Recovery mode).

I don't know exactly what packages fixed my computer, but I think the ones I tried was:

- xserver-xorg-video-all
- xserver-xorg-video-intel
- xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
- xserver-xorg-input-evdev
- xserver-xorg-video
- xserver-xorg

After installing these, I could finally boot the computer into a semi-working state (some graphical bugs) and install updates to fully get xorg working again.

Lukens solution with a network cable seems more intelligent now though..

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.  It was because my wireless wasn't functioning for some reason while xserver wasn't running.  I had to do a wired connection, then it all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the direction is bad writed, here is the really link:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg/xserver-xorg_7.6+7ubuntu7_amd64.deb

Comment: What can I do to fix this? There are a couple of errors regarding ../pool/main/x/.. as well though

Comment: Only click on the link and install manually

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I can only access the terminal through recovery mode since Ubuntu just gives me a blank screen now.

Comment: The URL I first wrote in my question was not the one I got in the error message, I've fixed it now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

The /etc/resolv.conf ineditable, to avoid DNS problem I had to add to /etc/hosts the ip of servers `echo "91.189.91.23 security.ubuntu.com" >> /etc/hosts 
echo "91.189.88.152 archive.ubuntu.com" >> /etc/hosts`