# Invisible text in Software Center

Tags: software-center, hybrid-graphics

After upgrading to Oneiric I hade some [graphical issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68693/could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-when-reinstalling-xorg), but now that I got them resolved, I encountered another issue. The start page for Software Center shows no text at all, though the single application pages works perfectly.

I can see the top 2-4 pixels of the text when hovering.

[image: Screenshot of Software Center]

I'm running 64bit Ubuntu 11.10 with hybrid graphics (Intel HD 3000 and AMD Radeon HD 6630M). Currently only the Intel card seems to work so the driver should be from xorg, xserver-xorg-video-intel?

Is this a problem with my graphics or is Software Center (or some corrupted dependencies) causing this? What can I do to make it work properly?

Comment: Since Software Center works for me, it must be your graphics :)

Comment: which graphics card is used? which driver?

Comment: I've updated my question with this information.

Comment: look in /var/log/Xorg.0.log, it tells you which driver is being used. Does switching to the Radeon change the issue?

Comment: What am I looking for in the log? Is it "intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets"? What I know, there is no Linux driver for the AMD card, so I've never had it working on Ubuntu.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).