# I am getting this error while running sudo apt-get update and it is telling that it was not able to fetch

Tags: 18.04

Using `sudo apt-get update`

[sudo] password for avinash:

[Output of  **ifconfig**,**cat /etc/network/interfaces**,**cat /etc/resolv.conf** Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6RQm.png)

[Output of **sudo lshw -C network**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpwNh.png)

[Output of **ip route**,**ip rule**,**ip link**,**iwconfig**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0UBB.png)

[Output of  **lspci -nnk**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Q3Q.png)

[Output of **dmesg| grep net**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V4wu.png)

[Output of **systemd-resolve --status**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Kyn.png)

[Output of **ping -c 5 8.8.8.8**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yznoD.png)

[Output of **mtr 8.8.8.8**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktpzr.png)

I get:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
  Could not resolve 'packages.microsoft.com'
Err:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you access any site on the internet at all from that system?

Comment: no,I am not able access any sites through terminal and I  am not able to install any thing

Comment: Going to need more information for anyone to be able to help you. Edit your question with the following information. Post the output of this command **ifconfig** and this command **cat /etc/network/interfaces** and this command **cat /etc/resolv.conf** and this command **sudo lshw -C network** and this command **iwconfig** and this command **ip link** and this command **ip rule** and this command **ip route** and this command **lspci -nnk** and this command **dmesg | grep net**

Comment: Those commands should give a better insight to the problem. Is it a dual boot system, and if so does the network work in the other system? If it is a cable network, check that the cable is plugged in to the computer and router properly, check you have leds on, and tell us what colours they are. Are you using a wifi or cable network connection.

Comment: Yes, Mine is dual boot system with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 8.1. I am connected to cable network with proxy authentication and it is plugged and working in windows.I am able to access internet through chrome in Ubuntu. But when  I am trying to run update or upgrade commands I am getting the above errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`apt-get update\` cannot find Ubuntu servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29071/apt-get-update-cannot-find-ubuntu-servers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com when reinstalling xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68693/could-not-resolve-archive-ubuntu-com-when-reinstalling-xorg)

Comment: How I can resolve this error

Comment: Okay, add in the output from **systemd-resolve --status** (I should have asked for that before), and also from **ping -c 5 8.8.8.8** and **mtr 8.8.8.8** if mtr is not on your system, add it by this command **sudo apt-get install mtr-tiny**